# How to go to tag on file in vim using CtrlP?

Tags: vim, vim-plugin

I'm using CtrlP and it mentions you can go to tag on a file.

How?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This answer is the most useful you'll ever get if you are serious about using Vim. Pay attention.

In normal mode, type:

```
:help
```

to access Vim's immense documentation.

To get help on an option, like `autochdir`, just type the following with the quotes:

```
:help 'autochdir'
```

and so on…

Most serious plugins come with a documentation, too. Here is how to read CtrlP's documentation:

```
:help ctrlp
```

where you will get your answer around line 833.

Don't thank me.

Answer (score 0):

You can search for tags with `:CtrlPTag`

Can also add a shortcut to .vimrc like so

```
nnoremap <leader>. :CtrlPTag<cr>
```